# Issue with respond time loader

Tags: jquery

I am usign jquery ajax method to send data to another page. But issue is I want to show response loader while fetching result from other page. I have id of img is #ajaxloader. BUt issue is when I show it, it continue to respond. that is if result is fetched its not hiding loader...I got script from google... but as I am sending data though $.post(), jquery method.
What should I replace for, .ajaxsend and .ajaxStop.

```
$().ajaxSend( function( r, s ) {
$("#ajaxloader").show();
});
$().ajaxStop( function( r, s ) {
$("#ajaxloader").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the success callback in `$.post` instead:

```
$('#ajaxloader').show();
$.post(url, data, function() {
    $('#ajaxloader').fadeOut();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/